# Generate specific key for specific code in Talend

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

i want to generate specific numbers for specific codes in talend. Some of the codes are repeating, but i dont want to generate a different numerical sequence for that code.
In tMap i used Numeric.sequence("out1.CODE",1,1) but it didnt help. Is there a way to replace the key based on the previous matching code. pls help

Table 1

| code |
| --- |
| ABC |
| ACC |
| AEB |
| ACC |
| AED |
| BEE |
| AEB |

Required Result

Table 1

| code | key |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 1 |
| ACC | 2 |
| AEB | 3 |
| ACC | 2 |
| AED | 4 |
| BEE | 5 |
| AEB | 3 |

Comment: implementation on postgres side will also do.

Comment: i've provide you the Talend Solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your job design would look like this

[image]

`1-  tMap_2 is configured as such`

[image]

`2- thashinput_1 would call thashoutput_1  and tick in the tUniqRow_1 : **Code**`

`3- tmap_4  configuration is configured as such :`

[image]

`4- tmap_5 configuration is configured as such :`

[image]

`Here is my output :`

```
Starting job string at 16:22 10/05/2022.
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3404
[statistics] connected
 .----+---.
 |tLogRow_3|
 |=---+--=|
 |code|key|
 |=---+--=|
 |ABC |1  |
 |ACC |2  |
 |AEB |3  |
 |AED |5  |
 |BEE |6  |
 |ACC |2  |
 |AEB |3  |
 '----+---'

 [statistics] disconnected

 Job string ended at 16:22 10/05/2022. [exit code  = 0]
```